# Bash: nested for loop over specific files in dir

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I have the following files in a DIR

```
File1.bam
File2.bam
File3.bam
File4.bai
File5.bai
```

I want to do something specific over all the .bam files

```
for i in ~/DIR; do
        for filename in *.bam; do
                FUNCTION -i $filename.bam -o $filename.bcf

        done
done
```

If i try to

```
echo "$filename"
```

I get

```
*.bam
```

back

I would want to have itterate over all the .bam files.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't go into DIR so *.bam does not list any files. You can simplify like this:

```
for filename in ~/DIR/*.bam; do
    echo $filename
done
```

Comment: Nope, it still prints literally ~DIR/*.bam

Comment: that means that there are no files in that place... before running your script, make sure the path is correct. probably `ls ~/DIR/*.bam` will tell you there are no such files; so correct this path.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot a slash for the path in looked somewhere else.